# Remove scene edge pixel error in annual composites in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, masking, composite, edge-detection

The median reducer over the cloud masked image collection is unable to remove the edge pixel error at a few scenes. Although the cloudmasking function has the code to remove such edge pixels not occurring in all scenes, but the median composites still has such errors at many location. The portion of composite with such error is attached along with the GEE code link for your kind reference and guidance.

I am getting such problems in a few more composites of another year. Please help me solve this issue.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/35fade3ad60b2634c1d9ec0d8fc748b5

[image: Composite with edge pixel errors]

Comment: I have a similar question. Did you find the answer to yours? I looked at your code and your images and it seems to have worked.